# Problem with newline in JavaScript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

i tried to do not show "SPAM" in string below using that regex:

```
alert("{SPAM\nSPAM} _1_ {SPAM} _2_".replace(/{[\s\S]+}/gm, ""));
```

What i was supposed to see was "~1~ ~2~"

(or something like that) but i got just ~2~. Why?

Answer (score 6):

`}` and `{` are also elements of the character class `[\s\S]`. You should avoid matching this by:

```
/{[^}]+}/g
```

so that the regex stops once the `}` is found.

Comment: Was about to post something about (un)greedy, but this is definitely better.